# Regex: Remove all special characters that are not apostrophes between letters

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like so:

```
s = "i'm sorry, sir, but this is a 'gluten-free' restaurant. we don't serve bread."
```

and I am trying to use re.sub to replace all special characters that are not apostrophes between letters with a space, so 'gluten-free' becomes gluten free and i'm will stay as i'm.

I have tried this:

```
import re

s = re.sub('[^[a-z]+\'?[a-z]+]', ' ', s)
```

which I am trying to say is to replace anything that is not following the pattern of one and more letters, with then 0 or one apostrophes, followed by one or more letters with white space.

this returns the same string:

```
i'm sorry, sir, but this is a 'gluten-free' restaurant. we don't serve bread.
```

I would like to have:

```
i'm sorry  sir  but this is a  gluten free  restaurant  we don't serve bread
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with a nested lookahead+lookbehind:

```
>>> s = "i'm sorry, sir, but this is a 'gluten-free' restaurant. we don't serve bread."
>>> print ( re.sub(r"(?!(?<=[a-z])'[a-z])[^\w\s]", ' ', s, flags=re.I) )
i'm sorry  sir  but this is a  gluten free  restaurant  we don't serve bread
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sWTKdJ/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?!`: Start negative lookahead

  - `(?<=[a-z])`: Positive lookbehind to assert that we have an alphabet at previous position
  - `'`: Match an apostrophe
  - `[a-z]`: Match letter `[a-z]`
- `)`: End negative lookahead
- `[^\w\s]`: Match a character that is not a whitespace and not a word character

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
import re
s = "i'm sorry, sir, but this is a 'gluten-free' restaurant. we don't serve bread."
print( re.sub(r"(?:(?!\b['‘’]\b)[\W_])+", ' ', s).strip() )
# => i'm sorry sir but this is a gluten free restaurant we don't serve bread
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/woR0F3) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yClPiC/1).

*Details*:

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `(?!\b['‘’]\b)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is an apostrophe within word chars
  - `[\W_]` - a non-word or `_` char
- `)+`  - one or more occurrences